# How to hide fbx files for commercial release

Tags: models, fbx, resource-management, 3d-modeling

I see that all commercial games I've played never expose their fbx files - usually, they archive the fbx files into PAK file or BIN file. For example, Torchlight 2 use  OGRE3D for their Graphic Engine, and at the loading screen, they un-pack the PAK file. How do they do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Commercial games usually don't use .fbx as their runtime format. They have converters that convert .fbx into their engine's own format because then they don't have to ship an .fbx reader that's huge/complex/not supported on all platforms.

Comment: To add to that, internal format is specifically crafted for the game to be efficient and fast to read/load into GPU.

Comment: But how do they do that (with OGRE)? Is there a tool or something?

Comment: Ogre does the same thing, there is a mesh class that holds all structures of a mesh. They simply read data and convert it to their own structure.